# different behavior of <xsl:number level="any"> between Saxon 8.7 and 9.1

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Does anyone know the reason why the following piece of XSLT prints "**1**" under saxon 8.7 and "**2**" under 9.1.0.8?

```
<xsl:variable name="count1">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp1"><x y="z"><x/></x></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$tmp1/x/x">
        <xsl:number level="any" from="x[@y='z']" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:message select="$count1"/>
```

And which value is the correct one?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if the change was introduced by this bug fix:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1460712&group_id=29872&atid=397617

However, there have been a number of other bug fixes to xsl:number over the years and it might be worth checking the others. Some were fixing bugs in the Saxon implementation, some were in response to errata in the spec: there has been a lot of clarification of corner cases over the years. Remember that 8.7 came out in 2006, before the XSLT 2.0 specification was finalized. (And the XSLT 1.0 spec for xsl:number was vague in the extreme.)

Michael Kay

Comment: Thanks. I guess 2 is the correct value. It is sad to see how over the years our code has come to depend on all the bugs in the old version of Saxon, that makes it so much harder to upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following through Saxon 8.7.3J and Saxon-HE 9.3.0.8J:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="count1">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp1"><x y="z"><x/></x></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$tmp1/x/x">
      <xsl:number level="any" from="x[@y='z']" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message select="$count1"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and they both printed '2':

```
~ zacharyyoung$ java -jar ~/Downloads/saxonb8-7-3j/saxon8.jar ~/so.xsl ~/so.xsl
2
```

-- and --

```
~ zacharyyoung$ java -jar /usr/local/saxon9he.jar -s:so.xsl -xsl:so.xsl
2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**EDIT 1**

The version supplied in OP's comment to this answer does indeed print '1':

```
~ zacharyyoung$ java -jar ~/Downloads/saxon-8.7.jar ~/so.xsl ~/so.xsl
1
~ zacharyyoung$ java -jar ~/Downloads/saxon-8.7.jar
No source file name
Saxon 8.7J from Saxonica
...
```

Comment: weird. I used this one from the Maven repo:  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/saxon/8.7/saxon-8.7.jar

Comment: @rustyx: Yep, that one does indeed print '1'.

Comment: Please note that any version of Saxon you find in Maven is unofficial, and has been put there by someone who has no respect for the license conditions, which require an acknowledgements of the contributions of third parties to accompany the software.

Comment: Thx, good to know... Do you know if there is an official version of Saxon in the Maven repo?